# Can the Death Note be filled up?

Tags: death-note

We see in *Death Note* that the pages of the Death Note are not self-healing, and pages torn out do not seem to be restored. At least some owners possess a Death Note for multiple years, and pages remain filled out with names written in the past (at least by the current owner). Still, the notebook is always depicted as a slim notebook.

[image: light's little black book]

[image: so many dead people]

If the owner manages to fill out all the pages, or tears out enough pages to need more, does the book somehow add pages, or is the owner no longer to write more names?

Comment: Can you write in pencil? Like write a name, await the death, then just erase it? ta da... unlimited space!

Comment: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/why-does-the-death-note-never-run-out-of-pages

Comment: @Möoz I am sure there is a canon death eraser but it also restore dead person

Comment: Related question from Anime.se [Why does the Death Note never run out of pages?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/why-does-the-death-note-never-run-out-of-pages)

Answer (score 5):

No the pages will never run out, as seen on the image[image]:

edit:
While i know some don't trust wikia sources, i don't have my deathnote manga's on me right now. i can confirm this however when i get home. for now, here is a [link](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXXI) to the wikia page where i got this info. additionally [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/deathnote/comments/3q8h40/death_note_rules/) is a reddit thread talking about this issue aswell

Comment: Without a source, this is meaningless. One can easily make a picture that says "Pages do run out" or worse

Comment: @Raditz_35 i have edited my answer withy some sources

Comment: Personally I think the *link* is good enough. This isn't a philosophy assignment where people complain about wiki, it's just that you posted a mostly black picture with some text on it that might have been from some fanfic facebook page

Comment: Yeah i can understand the issue there. Just for reference i will probably search my manga for a irl reference. Just in case. For now these links should profide some backup to my answer